# Which sage will learn the Vishnu Purana at the end of the Kali Yuga?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, vyasa, vishnu-purana

The sage Krishna Dvaipayana Vedavyasa (or Vyasa for short) is generally viewed as the author of the 18 Puranas.  But actually the sage Parashara, Vyasa's father, authored two of them, the Vishnu Purana and the Shiva Purana.  (Technically three, as Vyasa divided Parashara's Shiva Purana into the two texts we now call the Shiva Purana and the Vayu Purana.) In any case, the Vishnu Purana was narrated by Parashara to the sage Maitreya.  Now in the [last chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp163.htm) of the Vishnu Purana, Parashara tells Maitreya how he got the knowledge given in the Vishnu Purana and he makes a prophecy of what will happen in the future:

> Through the blessing of Vaśisht́ha it came to my knowledge, and I have now, Maitreya, faithfully imparted it to you. **You will teach it, at the end of the Kali age, to Śamíka.**

My question is, who is the sage Shamika that Maitreya will teach the Vishnu Purana to in the end of the Kali Yuga?  The only sage Shamika that I know is the one disrespected by Arjuna's grandson Parikshit, as described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/18/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> Once upon a time Mahārāja Parīkṣit, while engaged in hunting in the forest with bow and arrows, became extremely fatigued, hungry and thirsty while following the stags. While searching for a reservoir of water, he entered the hermitage of **the well-known Śamīka Ṛṣi** and saw the sage sitting silently with closed eyes.... While leaving, the King, being so insulted, picked up a lifeless snake with his bow and angrily placed it on the shoulder of the sage.... The brāhmaṇa’s son cursed the King thus: "On the seventh day from today a snake-bird will bite the most wretched one of that dynasty [Mahārāja Parīkṣit] because of his having broken the laws of etiquette by insulting my father."

By the way, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2964/36) it is to avenge Parikshit's death at the hands of a snake that Parikshit's son Janamjeya tried to perform a Yagna to try to get eradicate all snakes.  And it's during this Yagna that Janamejaya heard the Mahabharata from Vaishampayana.

In any case, is this the same sage Shamika that will learn the Vishnu Purana from Maitreya at the end of the Kali Yuga?  If so, why does he even need Maitreya to teach it to him?  The Vishnu Purana is known far and wide nowadays, so wouldn't it be easy for Shamika to learn the Vishnu Purana right now?

Are there any other scriptures that mention Shamika learning the Vishnu Purana at the end of the Kali Yuga? Is it mentioned in the Bhavishya Purana or Kalki Purana, for instance?

Comment: Some reasons I could see for teaching Vishnu Purana in the end of Kali yuga could be 1) As there are interpolations in almost all texts so maybe the right text needs to be taught. 2) Some additions of stories will be needed for Kalki incarnation. 3)There might be other incarnations of Lord Vishnu in between like Lord Venkateshwara or some other saints of today which we don't know today as incarnation but will be termed as incarnation in future. 4)Ved Vyasa is already given the duty to recompile the puranas so maybe Shamik is needed for his help.

Comment: Where is it said that Parashara was the compiler of the Shiva Purana? I thought it was Sanatkumara...

Comment: @Surya I've heard that the knowledge in the Shiva Purana was given by Sanatkumara to Parashara before it reached Vyasa, but I'm not sure what scripture mentions that.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe as we know a form of Buddhism survives as the predominant religion its going to be a astro/indian/aboriginal one and the grammatically taken vesture of the Vishnu Purana's sanskrit will be able to be made a construct in the minds of the max 3 1/2 foot pygmies!  Please think of the features form and likenesses in the mummified fossilized "65 yr old meditator from the last kali yuga" (simple google search suffices methinks) 
I reckon all this will happen as my vision is the elementary stutter proof and intonated catch up typo Sanskrit in Vishnu Purana will behove emotional value ... doing away any true MAYAVADI concepts of acit being ying/yang Dao as to tao that is to say to Spell it out the value of their war cries unto Kalkiraja will match up much ado like Indian/Bengali/Nepalese Varna does as good as the nicest way to go back to Goloka vraja 
but the horror types all bedecked to face Kalki Avatar well they just really deem themselves into a bliss that makes up what is only visable as a passing white cloud... all on the Strength of Sanskrit whom is a person eternal who as all do worships Rai~Kanu

So yeah that sage

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Answers on this site should be elaborate enough to solve the questioner's doubts and should contain relevant texts from Hindu scriptures, eg, Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads, etc to support your answer. Please either edit your answer to provide more details or delete/comment instead.

Comment: Mr. K.c are you a troll? Don't mind please, your answer made "no sense". Neither did your other answer make any sense.